# PHP sends BOM characters at the top of response

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I have a serious problem with php files encoded in utf-8. PHP return them with an extra BOM at the top, that makes a lot of problems like "headers already sent" in session_start or even unexpected views in browser(a big white space at the top!).
I have no problem with this on my local test server(Apache, XAMPP), but on my actual server(IIS, FastCGI) this problem happens.
I know that I can fix it by changing the encoding to "UTF-8 Without BOM", but it's a hard task to do with a lot of files. 

Also I want to know that what's the difference between my local and actual server that makes this problem. What does the problem originating from? And is there a way to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The way to solve it is by removing the BOM. It's a horrible feature. Often times it can cause issues when being uploaded as a text file over FTP where the encoding is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to find a way to solve it basically. And this ways are my next choices.

Comment: You really should remove the BOM. It's an aBOMination that increases the file size and reduces compatibility [and is completely unnecessary for UTF-8 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your problem is being originated, but I suggest you to use Notepad++ and record a macro. You open all of your php files at once(or some of them folder by folder), record the macro and let it do the job.

I've solved a similar issue like that.

Also please check your ftp client(if you use one) and make sure it doesn't convert your file type into `ASCII`.

Here is an example image from Filezilla FTP client. Make sure it's set to `Auto`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to find a way to solve it basically. And this ways are my next choices.